# Changing the color of a gameobject shows as white not the colour requested

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a set of gameobjects (simple cubes). I can set their initial colour when instantiating them. However when I try and change the colour by code, the object in the game view and inspector show as white, but in the colour picker show the correct colour!

There is a single directional light (the default one).

```
IEnumerator ColourChange()
{
    Color targetColour = new Color(Random.Range(0, 255), Random.Range(0, 255), Random.Range(0, 255));
    Debug.Log("color = " + targetColour);
    for (int x = 0; x < CreateCubeGrid.GRIDSIZE; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < CreateCubeGrid.GRIDSIZE; z++) {
            CreateCubeGrid.cubeGrid[x,z].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = targetColour;

        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.05f);
    }
}
```

[image: White graphics not coloured]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colours are 0 to 1 not 0 to 255.
Use Color32 if you want to use 0-255 values.

[Color32 Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the material's color, you must tell it exactly what color you're trying to change, by using `Shader.Find("_YourColor")` (Emission, Albedo, etc).

An approach that should work for materials using Standard Shader can be seen below:

```
private void ChangeColor(Color color)
{
    //Fetch the Renderer from the GameObject.
    Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    //Find and set the main Color ("_Color") of the Material to the new one
    rend.material.shader = Shader.Find("_Color");
    rend.material.SetColor("_Color", color);
}
```

You can read more about changing a Material's color at [Unity's Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html).